# Whats going on here, wide characters?

Tags: c

I'm trying to parse man pages, and the text it's parsing doesn't strcmp, strncmp, or memcmp right with normal strings, and the chars don't match up. Is this an issue with wchar_t? Heres what I do:

```
char man_page[1024], tok[1024]; 
char str1[] = "     #include <stdlib.h>";
FILE * fp = popen("man 3 div", "r");
fread(man_page, 1024, 1, fp);
strtok(man_page, "\n\r");
//...strtok then reaches the "     #include <stdlib.h>" line of man_page:
strcpy(str2, strtok(NULL, "\n\r"));
```

But then when I run:

```
printf(\"%s\":\"%s\", str1, str2);
for (int i=0; i<24; i++){
        printf("%c:%c\n", str1[i], str2[i]);
    }
```

I get the individual chars not matching, but the strings printing fine, like:

```
"     #include <stdlib.h>":"     #include <stdlib.h>"
 : 
 : 
 : 
 : 
 : 
#:#
 :i
#:n
i:c
 :l
i:u
n:d
 :e
n: 
c:<
 :s
c:t
l:d
 :l
l:i
u:b
 :.
u:h
d:>
```

Whats going on?

Comment: Where is there a `wchar_t` in your code? All I see are `char`s.

Comment: The output is just pretty-printed. You can run e.g. `popen("LANG=C LC_ALL=C COLUMNS=80 man 3 div | expand", "r")` to tell `man` to use the standard POSIX locale, with 80 characters per line, and pass the output through `expand` to replace tabs with the correct number of spaces, to get output closer to what you see when using `man` interactively.

Comment: And: did you try looking at a hexdump of the output from `man`?

Comment: i.e. `man 3 div | hexdump -C | less`?

Comment: So the hex dump is giving me `     #.#i.in.nc.cl.lu.ud.de.e <.<s.st.td.dl.li.ib.b...h.h>.>..` while when it prints to console char by char it gives me the same thing but with newlines substituted for the periods.

Comment: **Hex** dumps, learn to read them: they have two parts, a hexadecimal part on the left and an ASCII part on the right; in the ASCII part, non-ASCII bytes show as periods. In your example, the periods are not periods but backspaces -- `#` backspace `#i` backspace `in` and so on, to make the text bold on archaic printers. You may also want to look at a hex dump of the output of you own program.

Comment: If you're seeing doubled characters like `#.#i.in.n…`, the chances are good that the single dots are actually backspace characters (`'\b'` or `'\010'` or `'\x8'` or control-H) and the intent is that you end up with **bolder** text because on a dot matrix printer (or a daisy-wheel printer), you'd be printing the same character twice, but mechanical imperfections would mean that the character wasn't 100% accurately aligned the second time. It was a standard technique back in the dark ages (1980s, maybe into the 1990s). I still have a program `owl` for 'over-writing-lines' to do roughly that job.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The "#include.." line is displayed in bold and I was also on the track of text formatting. `printf("%d:%d",str1[i],str2[i]);` should show us the magic.